# How to edit the properties in SharePoint TeamsPersonalApp?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I have developed a WebPart. I'm using this WebPart in Teams as TeamsPersonalApp. This WebPart contains several properties to sync with AAD like: clientId, applicationId. If I use the WebPart in SharePoint, I can work with these properties, I can modify...

These are the properties in the WebPart:

```
 "preconfiguredEntries": [{
    "groupId": "---",
    "group": { "default": "Other" },
    "title": { "default": "----" },
    "description": { "default": "-----" },
    "officeFabricIconFontName": "Page",
    "properties": {
      "clientId": "--------",
      "tenantId": "--------",
      "width": "320",
      "height": "720",
    }]
```

The problem is that I need to edit the clientId and applicationId dinamically in Teams, but I don't know how can I do it.

My manifest has something like this, I have declarated a staticTab with these params:

```
 "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "example.integration",
      "name": "Example",
      "contentUrl": "https://{teamSiteDomain}/_layouts/15/TeamsLogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/_layouts/15/teamshostedapp.aspx%3Fteams%26personal%26componentId=xxxxx%26forceLocale={locale}",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

And with this config, I can't edit the values dinamically

[image]

I want to obtain something like this:

[image]

I'm stuck with this, I would know the way to change this values in Teams with the staticTab

Could somebody give a clue?

Regards!!

Comment: Are you trying to edit clientId, applicationId in the manifest? Also could you please share more details?

Comment: Hi @Nikitha-MSFT I have added more info. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @vcima, can you please help me understand your scenario to suggest anything to you. You get context in the team to have these values but i want to understand your scenario to suggest anything.